# Alterar o Bundle Identifier de uma app ja publicada na AppStore

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appstore

Publiquei uma App na App Store com o Bundle Identifier errado, acabei usando o nome(exemplo) "myapp" enquanto o correto seria "com.empresa.myapp" corrigi isso na nova versão mas gostaria  de saber se eu publicar com o Bundle alterado as pessoas que ja tem o meu app instalado vão receber a nova versão ou não?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente não. Uma vez aprovado e publicado, você não consegue mais modificar o Bundle Identifier, pois é através dele que o iTunes Connect percebe que você está mandando uma atualização, e não um novo app.

Link para documentação da Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html

Comment: Era isso que eu suspeitava, pois no aparelho de testes observei que quando mudei o Bundle e instalei ele não substitui o app pela nova versão mais adicionou um novo app, obrigado Rafael.